# Regex for name problem

Tags: java, regex, jflex

I need regex  for recognizing names which can be `[a-zA-Z_]` then `.` (dot) then again `[a-zA-Z_]`.
I `([a-zA-Z_]+) \.([a-zA-Z_]*)` but it doesn't work. Help ?
Can anybody give me hoe to do that in JFlex ?

Comment: Are you referring to a literal dot or the dot metacharacter (matching anything but a new line)?

Comment: My last edit was **only** code formatting, the backslash was present but invisible. (even though the edit *looks* as if I have added that backslash - that wasn't me, honestly!!)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? does it produce a regex compilation error? Does it fail matching something it should, or matches something it shouldn't?

Comment: @JaneNY - please show an (original) example name/input where this pattern doesn't match.

Comment: @JaneNY, from your previous posts, I make up you're trying to parse, and then evaluate boolean expressions. Instead of creating a parser yourself, have you considered using an existing (and proven!) one? Or perhaps Java's built-in script-engine can evaluate them on the fly for you?

Comment: And as a personal side note, if you're going to write it yourself, I highly recommend using ANTLR instead of JFlex. If you're completely new to parser generators, I find ANTLR to be much more intuitive than JFlex. If you have previous experience with GNU-Flex, then JFlex is a good first choice, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing regexp by escaping dot and removing space.

`([a-zA-Z_]+)\.([a-zA-Z_]*)`

additional suggestion to drop () and use temporary identifiers

edit: increasing reputation by commenting regexp

Comment: [Can regex answers include more detail in the explanation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73553/can-regex-answers-include-more-detail-in-explanation)

Comment: Even if it works: a downvote from me for posting (1) just a simple regexp without explanation *and* (2) not formatting that single line as code. But I can change my vote ;)

Comment: please do :] not that it matters

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the dot: "\." - otherwise, the regex parser treats it as the reserved "any char" symbol.

**-- EDIT --**
Now that we know that the dot IS escaped and therefore not the real problem: Are you sure the space before the dot is intentional?

Comment: (it was escaped - the backslash shows up as soon as you appy code formatting)

Comment: @Andreas_D: mmm... you are right. I suppose that the OP should provide more info.

Comment: If this pattern is copy-pasted from the original code, then, yes, I bet, the space before `\.` is the actual show stopper

Comment: @Andreas_D, no, the white space literals are ignored in JFlex rules. If you want to match a literal space in JFlex, either create a character class containing a space `[ ]`, or quote it: `" "`